# two sub div, one postion relative father div, the another relative browser?

Tags: html, css

this is my html
**a.html**

```
<div class='main'>
  <div class="sub1"></div>
  <div class="sub2"></div>
</div>
```

and css:
**a.css**

```
.main {
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.sub1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
}

.sub2 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 20px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

now I want `div.sub1` is relative to the parent div,
and `div.sub2` is relative to the browser,
how can I set style to `div.sub2`?

Comment: Pls provide more details

Comment: 'parent div' , not father ..

Comment: Then put second div outside the parent div.

Comment: @ketan then second div won't be child..

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge there are two possible solution either put second div outside the parent div. In this way `.sub2` will not be child of parent div.

Or make second div `position:fixed` instead of absolute.

```
.sub2 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 300px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 30px;
  left: 20px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/enznapsy/)**

Comment: but if has scroll bar``````

Comment: @nataila then i don't think there is any other solution.

Answer (score -2):

You need to set `.sub1` `position` as `relative` (instead of `absolute`).

```
.sub1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: and what difference it will make? did you get the question?

Comment: position is set to relative instead of absolute, if you compare it with the question.